# Adding data to already existing array of objects in c++

Tags: c++

I am stuck on this homework question. We have to create a c++ program where class is used to store details of employee and it should have two functions 1.To add details of employee and 2.To display details of all employees. User can select which function to use in runtime.
To be able to display detials of employees there should be some data hardcoded in program.
I am having problem while adding details of employees to this existing hardcoded data.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class DATA {
public:
    int ID;
string NAME, DESIGNATION, CITY;
DATA(int id, string name, string designation, string city) {
    ID = id;
    NAME = name;
    DESIGNATION = designation;
    CITY = city;
}

void add();
void showdata();
};
DATA employee[13] = {
    DATA(1, "Adam", "SrDev", "NY"),
    DATA(2, "Bob", "JrDev", "Paris"),
    DATA(3, "Charlie", "HRM", "Singapore")
};
```

I want to hardcode data of 3 employees and be able to add data of 10 more employees but I am getting this error.`NO instance of constructor "DATA::DATA" matches the argument list` Pls help..

Comment: Please [avoid posting images of code & errors](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Directly to the point, the "empty" spots in the array still need to be initialized and without a argument-less default constructor, the compiler cannot generate code to do the job.

Comment: Your code complies when you turn the `employee[13]` into `employee[3]`.

Comment: In the future, please add exact compilation errors.

Comment: Use `std::vector`. Immediately you no longer have a maximum of 13 employers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a default constructor to your class: `DATA() {}`

Since you provided less initializers than the number of elements in the array, the remaining elements need to be default-constructed, so a default constructor is needed.